# Using ModelMaker.m in FeynArts

Tags: feyncalc

I want to write a model file in FeynArts and I came across ModelMaker which takes in the Lagrangian as Input and then generates the .mod file. I am trying to make a model file for $\phi^4$ theory as a start. I have a couple of questions as I cannot yet use it:

1. What is the content of the .mmod file ?
2. The syntax for writing the Lagrangian:
   a) Fields are specified by `Field[...]`
   b) How do I write expressions like $\partial_\mu\phi\partial^\mu\phi$ ?
3. ModelMaker starts with `` BeginPackage["ModelMaker`", {"FeynArts`", "Global`"}] `` but there is no File or Folder Called Global in the FeynArts folder.

It would be very helpful if someone who has already written a model posts a demo of the code.

Answer (score 7):

AFAIK ModelMaker is not a very commonly used tool in model building. If you insist on using that, you probably should better contact Thomas Hahn directly.

What people usually use in [FeynRules](http://feynrules.irmp.ucl.ac.be/). Here is an example on implementing $\phi^4$-model and exporting in to FeynArts:

Phi4.fr

```
M$ModelName = "Phi4";

M$Information = {
  Authors      -> {"vsht"},
  Institutions -> {"TUM"},
  Emails       -> {""},
  Date         -> "September 15, 2016"
};

M$Parameters = {

  lambda == {
    ParameterType    -> External,
    ParameterName    -> \[Lambda],
    Description      -> "self-interaction coupling"
  }
};

M$ClassesDescription = {

  S[1] == {
      ClassName     -> phi,
      ParticleName    -> "\[Phi]",
      PropagatorLabel -> "\[Phi]",
      SelfConjugate -> True,
      Mass -> mphi
  }

};

LPhi4 = 1/2 del[phi, mu] del[phi, mu] - 1/(4!) lambda*phi^4 - 1/2 mphi^2*phi^2;
```

Then you save the following as a notebook to the same directory where you put Phi4.fr and run it to generate the model

```
FR$Parallel=False;
$FeynRulesPath=SetDirectory[$UserBaseDirectory<>"/Applications/FeynRules"];
<<FeynRules`;
SetDirectory[NotebookDirectory[]];
LoadModel["Phi4.fr"];
WriteFeynArtsOutput[LPhi4,Output->"Phi4"];
```

[image]
Finally you copy the created Phi4-directory to the Models directory of FeynArts and can start using the model

```
<<FeynArts`
$FAVerbose = 0;
top2To2 = CreateTopologies[1, 2 -> 2,ExcludeTopologies->{WFCorrections}];
diags2To2 = InsertFields[top2To2,  {S[1],S[1]}-> {S[1],S[1]},
        InsertionLevel -> {Classes}, Model -> FileNameJoin[{"Phi4","Phi4"}]];
Paint[diags2To2, ColumnsXRows -> {3, 1}, Numbering -> None,SheetHeader->None,ImageSize->{768,256}];
```

[image]

Comment: thank you very much for the code. Actually, i have a windows system so I was trying to use ModelMaker. Anyway I will try to run FeynRule.

Comment: ok I got it untarred for windows. Once again thanks